# JDOM `SaxBuilder` not releasing the malformed file

Tags: java, xml, jdom

In my application, I'm checking a value in the xml file, say `some.xml` and moving the file to another directory depending on the outcome of this read.

When `some.xml` is malformed, `SaxBuilder` is throwing the `JDOMException`, but not releasing the file. When i attempt to move `some.xml` after that, i'm getting the error that `some.xml` is used by another process.

my code is this (irrelevant details removed):

```
private static String getName(Path fullPath) {
    File f = fullPath.toFile();
    SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc = null;
    String result = ""; 
    try {
        doc = saxBuilder.build(f);
        result = doc.getRootElement().getChild("imageControl").getText();
    } catch (JDOMException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

so - after running this, on a malinformed xml passed in, that malinformed xml file is still open by the SaxBulider-- can't move it in my subsequent method.

How to fix this?

the only i can think of right now is to make a temporary copy of the xml and make the above reading on taht copy. but this is nowhere near the best thing.

I'm using JDOM 2.0.6 on Java 1.7

TIA.

//-----------------------------

EDIT:

the following fix in the corresponding lines didn't make it:

```
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f)){
        doc = saxBuilder.build(f);
```

the problem is **definitely** in this method. it's all running the expected way when I comment out its call.

//-----------------------------------------------

EDIT-2

nope - the typo.

```
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f)){
        doc = saxBuilder.build(is);
```

works.

Comment: Try to use `build(InputStream)` or `build(Reader)` methods instead and close stream/reader in finally block explicitly.

Comment: @Sergi With a little more detail that should be an answer, not a comment.  Also, I suspect JDOM `SaxBuilder(File)` forgets to close the input.

Comment: @Sergi write this as an ans and i'll accept. haven't yet tried but shd work.

Comment: I am looking through my code now, and JDOM does not actually have a file-handle on it. It delegates that to the XML parsr (typically Xerces). I will have more info in a few minutes. Can you give me an idea of whether you have a non-default XML parser installed (xerces, crimson, etc), or whether you are using the standard internal (custom xerces) XML parser built in to Java?

Comment: To work around this xerces/internal XML parser issue, I would also suggest a try/finally or try-with-resources using an InputSource-based-on-an-input-stream (not an InputStream directly - it loses some metadata context).

Comment: Yeah, this is an [issue in the xerces parser](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/parsers/AbstractSAXParser.java#1206) - it creates a byte or character stream from the file-URL, but does not close it. I recall that this is documented. Trying to find it somewhere....

Comment: @rolfl no other xml/related tools in the env. hven't even heard of xerces. the FileInputStream is the only closeable in that code and it's not making it

Comment: @user6762070 - JDOM is not technically an XML parser, it uses the XML parser embedded in your Java runtime - and that XML parser is xerces. JDOM (and you) are a victim of a bug in Java itself....

Comment: @rolfl well - will keep an eye on it from now on. JDOM could've worked it around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that SaxBuilder does not close resources, so please try to use `build(InputStream)` or `build(Reader)` methods instead and close stream/reader in finally block explicitly.
I would agree with @Jim Garrison, that JDOM probably forgets to close the input in case of an exception.

Comment: @user6762070 With regards to your edited answer: your code still uses file, not the stream due to a typo. It shall be `saxBuilder.build(is)` while you have `saxBuilder.build(f)`